# Best way to fit an ARIMA model when the values of the variables don't change

Tags: time-series, arima

I have a time series with various features that record sensor data. It can be the case that the values are recorded although they did not change compared to the previous observation. Hence, the series has multiple parts where the values of many consecutive observations are constant. 
As far as I know, this is very problematic when fitting an ARIMA model. My idea is to simply remove the parts of the series where nothing changes, thereby only fitting the model to the parts where things actually happen. Does this make any sense or will I mess up the coefficients that way?

Answer (score 0):

Let me rephrase what you are doing to show whether I understood it correctly.

1. You start from the *original* series that has some repeated observations.
2. You then omit each data point that coincides with the data point that immediately precedes it; this way you obtain a *transformed* series; 
    alternatively, you may omit each data point that coincides with the data point immediately subsequent to it.
3. Then you fit an ARIMA model to the *transformed* series.

Naturally, such an estimated ARIMA model would fit the *transformed* series. The fitted model could be used to explain (as far as ARIMA models can be interpreted as explanatory models) or to predict the *transformed* series. With respect to the *transformed* series, the model may be "good" and problems like "messed up coefficients" need not arise.

However, you should not expect that the model would make sense with respect to the *original* series. Indeed, it might be very far from a "good" model with respect to the *original* series. It need not explain or predict the *original* series well.

What you could do instead is build a combination of two models:

1. an ARIMA model for the periods when changes happen and
2. a constant model for the periods when no changes happen

with a separate process determining when each of the regimes prevails. That would constitute a regime-changing model with two regimes.